# How can I check if there is a new line?

Tags: java, string, file

this program is supposed to convert something like:

```
\hyp76{a,1+a-b}b{xy}
```

to:

```
\HyperpFq{7}{6}@@{a,1+a-b}{b}{xy}.
```

As you can see, if the contents of a group is one character, then there are no brackets. However, when one of the groups with brackets is at the end of a line, it skips over that group and treats that as the single character(without brackets) case. How can I avoid this? Thanks. Here is my code:

```
static int checkNestedBrackFront(String line, int pos){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=pos;i<line.length();i++ ){
        if(line.charAt(i)=='{')
            count++;
        if(line.charAt(i)=='}'&&count==0)
            return i;
        if(line.charAt(i)=='{')
            count--;
    }
    return 0;
}

line = new Scanner(new File("KLSadd.tex")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Converted.tex");
    while(line.contains("\\hyp76")){
            int posHyp = line.indexOf("\\hyp76");
            String beforeHyp = line.substring(0,posHyp);
            int start = posHyp+7;   
            String firstArgs = line.substring(start, line.indexOf("}", start));
            if(line.charAt((line.indexOf("}", start)+1))!='{'&&!(line.substring(start, start+4).contains("\n"))){ //this is to check for single characters
                secArgs = line.substring(line.indexOf("}", start) + 1,line.indexOf("}", start) + 2 );
                posSec=line.indexOf("}", start)+1;
            }
            else {
                int posBrack = line.indexOf("{", line.indexOf("}", start));
                posSec = checkNestedBrackFront(line, posBrack+1);
                secArgs = line.substring(posBrack+1, posSec);
            }
            if((line.charAt(posSec+1)!='{')&&!(line.substring(posSec,posSec+4).contains("\n"))){ //this is to check for single characters
                System.out.println(line.charAt(posSec+1)+"hello");
                 thirdArgs= line.substring(posSec+1,posSec+2);
                 afterHyp=line.substring(posSec+2);
            }
            else{
            int posThirdBrack = line.indexOf("{", posSec);
            int posThird = checkNestedBrackFront(line, posThirdBrack+1);
            thirdArgs = line.substring(posThirdBrack+1,posThird);
            afterHyp = line.substring(posThird+1);
            }
            line=beforeHyp+"\\HyperpFq{7}{6}@@{"+firstArgs+"}{"+secArgs+"}{"+thirdArgs+"}"+afterHyp;
        }
      writer.print(line);
    writer.close();
```

Comment: Very confusing.  Try clarify your question.  What is the single character case?  What is the brackets case? What is this useless function 'checkNestedBrackFront' that returns 0?

Answer (score 0):

a little bit confusing , but as I understood you wan to detect a new line :

```
 PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Converted.tex");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("KLSadd.txt"))
                .useDelimiter("\n");
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String  lne = scanner.next();
        String[] lines =  lne.split("YOUR DELIMETER");
        for(int j=0;j<lines.length;j++){
            line = lines[j];
            //the rest of your logic  goes here
            }
```